# Error what not getting subtotal in Ext.js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to get subtotal of a column but I can't get subtotal for a column of a grid on Sencha Ext.js. I shared the codes and screenshot below. How can I solve this error?

```
summaryRenderer: function(val, params, data, metaData) {
     return '<span style=color:#00B2EE;font-weight:bold;text-align: center;>' +val+'</span>'};
```

[example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5krM.png)

Comment: Hello, can you maybe share the config of your grid and columns or a https://fiddle.sencha.com ?

Answer (score 0):

undefined mean you not send value to function, try console before draw "val" in summaryRenderer function